# Customize default Laravel CSS

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, css, laravel, sass

In `Laravel <= 5.0`, there is a predefined app.css coming from bootstrap.

I would like to customize it (for example enlarging the base font-size to 16px), but keeping the custom font-family of Laravel (Roboto).

I could change the .scss file and recompile it, but if i go in:

```
laravel\resources\assets\sass\app.scss
```

This just points to the default boostrap (not the customized laravel scss):

```
// @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

I wonder why the original customized laravel scss isn't present, and how I could customize it?

Ps. editing the `/public/css/app.css` directly isn't a good idea

Comment: I haven't worked with scss yet, but have you already checked  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/elixir#sass ?

Answer (score -2):

Your default CSS file resides here:

```
laravel\public\css\app.css
```

You can edit that one all you want.

Comment: i know, but that is not the .scss !